# Can I prevent NuGet from downgrading (parameterized) references in my project files?

Tags: f#, msbuild, nuget, teamcity

This happens sometimes, not always and I can't describe precisely what circumstances are needed to replicate it:

- I have a test project in F# 4.0, that naturally references FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0
- The test project uses FsUnit which is added through NuGet
- On `-ReInstall` or update/restore, the FSharp.Core reference gets downgraded to FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1

Essentially the following line in the `.fsproj` file:

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core, Version=$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion), Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

gets replaced with:

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
  <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.0.0.1\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I would very much like to prevent that from happening, especially on the TeamCity build-server, which currently has different test results from local builds as a result of this behavior.

I tried playing with [`-DependencyVersion:HighestPatch`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference), but this appears to have no effect here.

Comment: One way to avoid issues with package restore is to [not use package restore](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/29/nuget-package-restore-considered-harmful) ;)

Comment: @MarkSeemann, yes, well, nice blogpost, but I'm generally glad we added this single extra dependency called NuGet, making it typically a run once, run everywhere experience. All those unversionable binaries, all different versions (.net4, .net46, x86, x64, msil and its combinations), let alone the configuration issues that arise from script-only packages (like method weaving Fody) if you have to run them locally-only are a nightmare. We used to have that, and it had more trouble than it solved. Though a possible middle ground would be to run our own NuGet server, but we're not there yet.

Comment: Not to forget: diff'ing on binaries is virtually impossible and DVCS's typically store the whole blob, not the diff, for binaries. With presently about 120MB of external dependencies, our DVCS would become insanely big very quickly...

Comment: 120 MB ~ 12 cents of disk drive storage... Sure, if you update your dependencies *all the time*, it'll add up, but if you have to do that, it's a smell that you're violating the *stable dependency principle*...

Comment: @MarkSeemann: there is something to say for your argument and for a long while I was "in your camp", but I've been "turned" ;). It is not about the cost. It is about a prj that runs for years (since 2007 to be precise), and most dependencies have updates at least two times, but often more times a year, incl. security updates. It is then the _download time_ of the whole repo on clean check-outs, and the increasing cost of backups that starts to add up. The "old style" repo has grown over some 15GB, the "new style" is hardly 800MB with the same deps.

Comment: But the real issue is actually configuration. We used to have to do a lot of manual tweaking of `.target` files, `fsproj`, `csproj` etc, which is a pain. Now we still need to do some of that, but most of it is hidden through NuGet. Yes, it comes with a downside, but at least it (typically) runs the same everywhere and it has (almost) zero configuration cost. But, though very interesting, we're digressing... NuGet is a fact of live, and like .NET was considered harmful in the beginning, some things just happen and we have to live with its perks.

Comment: (until something better comes around, of course)

Comment: Have you considered Paket?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem and haven't found a solution yet.